# Joining Data Frame & SQL Server table directly and update table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, etl

I am new to Python, looking for options on direct join (Just like sql join b/w tables) between Data Frame and SQL Server table and Insert/update table(s).Is there way to join and Insert/update without using Temp table or Cursor.

Reason : In actual scenario, i have millions of rows between the tables DF & SQL Server Tables.My understanding is .....using temp table or cursor is expensive process.
So looking for options.

This is how the Dataframe looks like:

```
            name      author     count
         0  a         b          10
         1  c         d          5
         2  e         g          2
```

I need to join it with a SQL Server table that looks as below:
TABLE: Books

```
          title   author    url         Count
          a       b         a.com.      Null
          b       z         b.com.      Null
          e       g         c.com.      Null
```

I want to join df & Books on df.name & Books.title and
insert missing rows from df  into Books and
update Count column from df.

```
  Insert into Books (title  ,author  ,url ,Count)
  select name, author, count 
  from df left join Books on df.name =  Books.title
  where Books.title is null 

 update Books
 set Count = df.Count
 from df Inner join Books on df.name =  Books.title
```

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this.
Thanks!

Result :

```
    title   author    url         Count
    a       b            a.com.  10
    b       z            b.com.  5
    e       g            c.com.  2
    c       d            Null    5
```